Excel Template Report with Conditional Grouping Logic
I want to develop a BI Publisher report using Excel Template, this would have 2 Queries in the Data Model referring different Columns based on 2 SQL Queries. The Output for the report is expected to show One of the Query Output, so I want to have Excel output showing the Data fetched from One query at a time.
Is there a function in XDO to dynamically refer the sheet, that brings the output of the required Group (SQL Query). Is there some function that to be defined on the Metadata Sheet to refer the desired Sheet?
